# getting graphQL error when compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

i am going through this tutorial: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2017-07-19-creating-a-blog-with-gatsby/

I have completed everything, and I am getting a graphQL compile error:

```
GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's GraphQL queries.
Invariant Violation: GraphQLParser: Unknown argument `formatString`. 
Source: document `BlogPostByPath` file: `GraphQL request`.
```

Here is my query:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostByPath($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        path
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
;
```

The compile error points to the date object, and when i remove it, the date compile error goes away. What is wrong with my date object?

Comment: Probably a date format issue, try using one of those ones : https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/7945bc569687d54b1bb761f4615b694fb65681fe/packages/gatsby/src/schema/infer-graphql-type.js#L45

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your date object `date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")` itself.

Rather, check your markdown file and make sure you are using the proper format in your frontmatter. I assume that's where your issue is stemming from.

**Examples:**

A date like this (*there's no 77th month in a year*) will throw the error you are getting:

```
---
path: "/hello-world"
date: "2017-77-12"
title: "My First Gatsby Post"
---
```

Similarly, a date like this (*there's no 88th day in a month*) will also throw the error you are getting:

```
---
path: "/hello-world"
date: "2017-07-88"
title: "My First Gatsby Post"
---
```

Those are extreme examples, but I think you catch my drift by now, so try fixing your frontmatter date so that the month, day, and year make calendrical sense.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue; fixed all my dates as  recommended but the error still persisted. At the time of testing, I was running in Powershell:

`gatsby develop`

I stopped that using <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> and `Y` to cancel, restarted the gatsby development server and the query then worked. When in development mode, gatsby caches certain things and it wasn't picking up the frontmatter changes to my files.

Comment: I had the same issue except it wasn't the content I had filtered on ($path) that had the error. it was a different subset of pages that had the wrong date (using the same field name). Make sure to check all your dates using a string query for the date field in gatsby's ___graphql tool. You can easily see all the date nodes

Answer (score -4):

It should be "MMM" rather than "MMMM".